# How to remove object from an Array which is under an object Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a data set like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bacc98431481e0520856df8"),
    "action" : {
        "count" : 0,
        "shop" : [ 
            {
                "uid" : ObjectId("5c0b396a50b8a627c4172a2b"),

            }, 
            {
                "uid" : ObjectId("5c0b3b471ed11f2124e1e3a8"),

            },
            {
                "uid" : ObjectId("5c0b3b471ed11f2124e1e3a9"),

            }
         ]
      }
}
```

How will I remove the above object whose `uid` is `ObjectId("5c0b3b471ed11f2124e1e3a8")` through mongodb Query?

I used with the approach which is not perfect according to me. My approach is like this:

```
db.CollectionName.find({_id: ObjectId("5bacc98431481e0520856df8")})
.then(data => {
  if (data.length > 0) {
        let xData = data[0].notifications.shop;
        let xuid = ObjectId("5c0b3b471ed11f2124e1e3a8");
        let filterData = xData.filter(
          x => x.uid!= xuid
        );
        User.update(
          { _id: ObjectId("5bacc98431481e0520856df8")},
          {
            $set: {
              action: { shop: filterData }
            }
          }
        )
        .then(usr => {
          console.log("deleted successfully")
         })
         .catch(er => {
           console.log(er)
         })
  }
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

By this approach I remove the `uid` from an array which itself under an object. If anyone knows this type of task done through MongoDB Query then please let me know.

Any Help/Suggestion is really appreciated. Thanks in advance for the developer who attempted my Query.

Comment: Try this `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id": ObjectId('5bacc98431481e0520856df8') },
  { "$pull": { "action.$.shop": { "uid": ObjectId('5c0b3b471ed11f2124e1e3a8') }}}
)`

Comment: dear @AnthonyWinzlet i followed your query and get the error that is MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo statement to do this would be:

```
db.getCollection('YOURCOLECTION').update(
{'_id': ObjectId("5bacc98431481e0520856df8")}, 
{ "$pull": 
       { "action.shop": { "uid": ObjectId("5c0b3b471ed11f2124e1e3a8") }} 
})
```

You would be using [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) command in combination with the `$update`.

Comment: Dear, I follow your query, according to this nothing is pulled on an array. i got the mongodb response that is : { n: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1544246568 },
     t: 374 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000176,
  ok: 1,
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1544246568 },
  '$clusterTime':
   { clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1544246568 },
     signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: 0 } } }

Comment: here nModified is 0 not 1

Comment: I tested it locally with your exact data on mongoDB 3.6 so I am pretty sure that the query is solid.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct `collection` in `db.getCollection('YOURCOLECTION')` etc

Comment: Yes You are right, actually I have done a mistypo error, thats the reason, anyways thanks and I accepted the answer